# Put only the List<id,Name> from Entity into Viewbag."EntityName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdown

Using the `ReleatedEntity` I already get a list of the related entities. But I only want to stick the Id+Name in a viewbag so that Razor can bind the dropdown.

Question: 
**How to get only `Id`, `Name` of Entity as a `List`** so that I can bind it to `DropDowns` in ASP MVC 5 in razor*; *and put it as* Viewbag.Attribute, i.e. ViewBag.EntityName

Edit 1: Simplified my code

```
foreach (var relatedFkEntity in (((IEntityWithRelationships)EntityType.FirstOrDefault())
 .RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds()))
 {
 // EntityNameHere  <- how to stick the Id and Names list there from the EF entities
    viewbag.**Entity Name Here** = dropdownListWithId&Name; //??
    entity.Include(relatedEntity.TargetRoleName).ToList();                     
 }
```

Comment: There appears to be a lot of custom work here so it's hard to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @Shoe first, thanks for taking a look. I can simplify it. My code gets the list of entities. And foreach entity,  _I just want to get the `key/Id` and the `Name` so that I can wire to the `dropdownControl` in ASP MVC razor from the viewbag._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please have a look following code, please make changes this has not been tested

```html
foreach (var relatedFkEntity in (((IEntityWithRelationships)EntityType.FirstOrDefault    ()).RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds()))
{

      viewbag.drpList = new SelectList(entity.Include(relatedEntity.TargetRoleName).ToList(), "Id",     "Name");
                         
}
```

Comment: Hi, its showing errors I tried to run it at http://dotnetfiddle.com , Two things, the `entitytype` at the viewbag, I was trying `viewbag.+this.GetType().Name.ToSTring() = new selectlist....` I want to add the name of the entity to the viewbag